# Message: [] operator not supported for strings

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I click edit button, showing this error to me. And this project come form this  [Github repo](https://github.com/hubinjie/ACI)

[image]

**php environment:**

> PHP 7.1.14 (cli) (built: Feb  7 2018 18:33:30) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
>   1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018
>   Zend Technologies

Here is from 220-228, and whole code in this [github repo](https://github.com/hubinjie/ACI/blob/master/application/controllers/adminpanel/ModuleMenu.php), because too much code cannot upload here

```
$result = $this->Module_menu_model->select('','*,`menu_id` as id','','list_order ASC,menu_id DESC');
            foreach($result as $r) {
                $r['cname'] = $r['menu_name'];
                $r['selected'] = $r['menu_id'] == $datainfo['parent_id'] ? 'selected' : '';
                $array[] = $r;
            }
            $str  = "<option depth='\$depth'  value='\$id' \$selected>\$spacer \$cname</option>";
            $tree->init($array);
            $select_categorys = $tree->get_tree(0, $str);
```

Comment: How is `$array` defined?

Comment: `[]` for array declaration is supported in php7+ - check PHP version and as @Mureinik said, check how `$array` is defined

Comment: @YuyangHe the first place it's assigned. Also - what PHP version are you using?

Comment: @Mureinik PHP 7.1.14, I wrote in my question

Comment: @Mureinik please check this link for whole code.. https://github.com/hubinjie/ACI/blob/master/application/controllers/adminpanel/ModuleMenu.php

Comment: $array is defined as a string on line 216, which causes the error.

https://github.com/hubinjie/ACI/blob/master/application/controllers/adminpanel/ModuleMenu.php#L216

Comment: Remove $array assignment from the list on line 216 and assign as an array separately

Comment: $array[] = $r; declare $array above the for loop like $array = array();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make following changes  to your code then try

```
    $result = $this->Module_menu_model->select('','*,`menu_id` as id','','list_order ASC,menu_id DESC');
   $array = array();
                foreach($result as $r) {
                    $r['cname'] = $r['menu_name'];
                    $r['selected'] = $r['menu_id'] == $datainfo['parent_id'] ? 'selected' : '';
                    $array[] = $r;
                }
                $str  = "<option depth='\$depth'  value='\$id' \$selected>\$spacer \$cname</option>";
                $tree->init($array);
                $select_categorys = $tree->get_tree(0, $str);
```

Notice $array variable declared as array.

Answer (score 0):

Remove $array assignment from the list on line 216 and assign as an array separately